# Can I (Reliably) Use TransferEncoding.EightBit On An Attachment With SmtpClient?

Tags: c#, .net, email, encoding, smtp

I'm trying to send a binary file as an email attachment using .Net's SmtpClient.  By default, the behavior I'm seeing is that the attachment is sent as a Base64 string.  So if I have something like a 3mb file on disk, when I attach it and mail it, the result is between a 4-5mb .eml file.

I had a quick look at the `TransferEndcoding` Enum, hoping for something like 'binary', but no such luck.  Still, if I choose 8-bit encoding, the attachment/message is smaller and the file's integrity was fine.  I've tested it a few times, with different files, and it seems to work.

My concern is this:

> The data is in 8-bit characters that may represent international
>   characters with a total line length of no longer than 1000 8-bit
>   characters. For more information about this 8-bit MIME transport
>   extension, see IETF RFC 6152.

What determines the line length?  Is it just luck that the binary data being encoded happened to have an 8-bit character that maps to a new line every 1000 or less characters in my examples.....but that using 8-bit encoding is not a viable solution for email attachments?

Answer (score 1):

`Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit` is intended for international *text*, not images, videos, zip files, or anything else that would be binary content.

If you want to be able to send messages over SMTP that contain binary content, you'll need to use `Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary` which is not possible using System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.

To send binary content, you will need to use another mail library such as [MailKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit) (which is written by me). In fact, I don't think any other mail library for .NET supports the SMTP BINARY extension.